# How do I restart Orca?

Tags: restart, orca

Orca has been crashing a lot lately.. and I don't know how to restart it. Is there any way to do this from the command line?
I cannot find Orca anywhere in the main menu.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Orca FAQ on Using Orca](http://live.gnome.org/Orca/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/UsingOrca), simply run (from a command line)

> nohup orca

If that does not work, I see in the Ubuntu packages that this is named "gnome-orca", so you might try that as a second effort.

The 'nohup' in front lets you close the terminal window after restarting, without killing the process it started.